# Django cannot see the new column I've added to both my table and my model

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, django-models

Here is the 'maps_accesspoint' table in a MySQL database:

```
id              int(11)         NO  PRI     auto_increment
name            varchar(255)    NO          
location        varchar(255)    NO          
geolocation     varchar(255)    NO          
restricted_area varchar(3)      YES
```

And its Django model:

```
class AccessPoint(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    geolocation = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    restricted_area = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

However, when accessing this model via Django Admin I get the following error:

```
Exception Value:    
(1054, "Unknown column 'maps_accesspoint.restricted_area' in 'field list'")
```

What is wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you migrated your database since you made your changes?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, Nagra. Actually I've just found out that my settings.py was pointing to production database. I've just changed it to local db and now Django is able to see the db changes. 

So if anyone come to this post in a similar situation, please always remind checking if your local environment is pointing to the right database (the one you've altered) at settings.py. 

Thanks once again.

Comment: And no, I'm doing the changes manually instead of running migration as it seems to be the easier thing to do at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to not update manually your database. The easiest solution might be to delete maps_accesspoint table and run syncdb again.

Remember, every time when you change your model you have to update your database. You can do it manually or using this [south](http://south.aeracode.org). But if you have Django 1.7 you might look at [migrations in Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/).